# Multiple prompted arguments in Perforce (P4V) Custom Tools?

Tags: perforce

Can I create a Custom Tool in P4V that prompts a user for multiple arguments?

The setting is worded in such a way that it seems possible - 'Prompt user for arguments', but I've tried putting various separator-type characters into the Description field and I only ever get a single prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only have one, but of course your custom tool can parse out a comma or space delimited set of arguments.

Comment: I don't like this answer, but I guess that doesn't make it wrong.